# How can I make discord not show what game I'm playing?

Tags: discord

Discord will show what game you're playing, but I don't want it to do that.

Is it possible to make discord not show the game currently being played?

Comment: Close discord ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/494q04/is_there_a_way_to_stop_showing_what_game_im/d0p0ara):

> User settings > Games > untick `Display Currently running game as a status message`

[image: Settings screenshot]

Comment: Thanks. Just a note that this option only shows up on the desktop version (though I don't think the web app shows the game, anyway).

Comment: this isnt an option on either!

Comment: @renegade If you're using the mobile version then it seems this option isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

The web version will show the game you are in.  The Web version does not have the Games tab that allows you to change this options.