# Why is Discord displaying what I’m playing when I have no connections?

Tags: discord

I connected Discord to my Xbox Live account and I played a game. I stopped playing, later disconnected my Xbox Live account from Discord, and it still says I’m playing the game I was playing even though I wasn’t even on the Xbox. It said I was playing a certain game for 22 hours, and I can’t turn it off. I have the Discord mobile app, and my friend took it off. Later I went back on that game and the same thing happened. How do I fix this?

Comment: UPDATE: discord has fixed the problem. I no longer have it

Comment: If you are still here, please leave an answer saying it was a bug that has been patched and mark it as the accepted answer so this question is then marked as accepted.

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per Nick S' answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off this display setting in the Discord client:

```
User settings > Games > untick Display Currently running game as a status message
```

This is off by default until you connect your Discord account to Xbox/etc. After that it will display what it thinks you're playing.

This is a possible duplicate question, see [this post.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/286903/how-can-i-make-discord-not-show-what-game-im-playing?rq=1)

Comment: I'm not sure the user is asking the same question here. Seems like he doesn't mind having the game displayed, but instead the wrong game is displaying (it's showing him in a game when he's not). While this is a potential solution, it's not going to fix anything if he also wants to be able to show his current game.

Comment: @kfan discord will sometimes incorrectly guess what you're playing- unchecking and rechecking the box, especially in the client, should fix the issue (it did for me)

Comment: I've personally had my current game turned off for forever, so this is good to know. Probably worth editing into the answer above then?