# How to hide what I'm playing from Discord?

Tags: discord

I have Discord installed and set the Activity Privacy to this:

[image: Screenshot of activity privacy settings, with "Display current activity as a status message." toggled off.]

Whenever I play a certain game, I get this notification in my settings:

[image: Screenshot of "Go live" bar in Discord, showing the currently played game, with username and game title censored by the uploader.]

In the *Registered games* section, I have found the game I play and though I set it to not display, it is still visible.

After quitting the game, I removed it from the *Registered games* with the red X.

Strangely, I can't remove it while playing.

[image: Screenshot of game showing up in "Registered games" section of the settings, despite it being set to not display.]

After starting the game, I see the notification again.

What else can I do to ***stop Discord showing my currently played game*** within the client?

Comment: Discord is always at the ready to stream a game you're playing. You can hide your activity from your friends, but I don't think it's possible to disable this specific feature.

Comment: I want to preemptively address possible close votes. This question is different from [this similar post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/286903/how-can-i-make-discord-not-show-what-game-im-playing?rq=1) because the Asker has already addressed the Display Activity settings and is seeking to hide the game on their own screen and from their Registered Games list, not just from their friends or server members.

Comment: If connected to Xbox, you cannot even hide your status from friends, in my experience.

Comment: Is it EXE name based? Because those can be changed?

Comment: May I suggest editing the question title to "How to hide what I'm playing **to** Discord?" (or a better wording) It would help clarify that it is the Discord app that should not know what OP is playing, not other users.

Comment: @Invizio "from" works even better

Comment: @PausePause: It's not actually clear that that's the intent. From the original question text, we can't tell whether the questioner wants to hide it on their own screen, or whether they think Discord is still showing their current game to other users despite the settings. (The current question text is the result of edits by another user.)

Comment: An interesting alternative question might be: How to publish and play a specifically titled game for the purpose of getting the activity status to show "**Fxxx Discord! Now playing!**"

Answer (score 39):

**Use discord in the browser**

Unfortulately, Discord does not provide any built-in option to do that. However, if you use the browser version, Discord will be confined to your browser's sandbox and won't be able to scan your computer for running apps, and most¹ other features should work properly.

---

@aphid's answer is generally correct, although as is now, the most convenient solution is hidden among many suggestions which are possible for power users, but overkill for most Discord users (deploying a VM, installing a VPN, reverse-enginerring Discord, etc). I'd like to put more emphasis on what most people should consider:

If you goal is *only* to stop Discord from finding out which games you play, as @PausePause pointed out, Discord itself does not provide any option for that. The closest that can be achieved is by running Discord in a browser, which will confine Discord inside a secure sandbox and will prevent it from exploring the rest of your system.

Note that this will also disable a few other features that also require access outside the sandbox¹. However, I've been using Discord in a browser everyday for over a year, and it works well, so it may be a viable solution for you. Best is to try!

---

¹: Certain features like push-to-talk/push-to-mute won't work if you don't have the browser window focused, but all important features (voice chats, screen sharing, etc.) should work fine.

Comment: I don't see how this adds anything new to the existing answers.

Comment: @Joachim It expands on the option of using Discord in a browser. aphid does mention it, but only as the third bullet point of the third paragraph of their answer, without expanding on it. I believe this option deserves better coverage than that, to attract more attention on it and to state its drawbacks. As for PausePause's answer, although correct in that there is no straightforward solution, it does not state any alternative solution, whereas mine does.

Comment: @Joachim This gives me an upvote target for the 'use the browser' version, which is different from aphid's answer that I choose not to upvote as I don't care for the editorializing.  It deserves to be separate.

Comment: Does discord work in incognito/private mode in the browser?

Comment: @mcalex Yes, it works as well in private browsing as in regular browsing. The only difference is that you'll have to login each time you close and reopen private tabs.

Answer (score 28):

**Discord will always detect what game you're playing.**

This is a core feature of the service and cannot be disabled using standard settings. As you noted, you can toggle the "Display current activity as a status message" setting to hide what game you're playing from other friends on discord. The service will still show what you're playing to you, but nobody else can see it.

[This continues to be an occasional complaint on the Discord forums](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360054291931-Option-to-disable-ANY-detection-of-running-games)

Comment: Also a good reason to use free software alternatives that respect user privacy, such as Element (Matrix client).

Comment: I use the browser version precisely for this. The browser cannot detect what games I'm playing.

Comment: @qwr Do you know that Discord doesn't respect user privacy in this regard? The Discord application installed and running on my PC knowing that I'm also running a game on my PC isn't a privacy concern in and of itself; it's only a privacy issue if it's sending that information elsewhere at any point.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist They used to have a clause in their terms of service saying that they collected application lists, but I don't see it anymore.

Answer (score 18):

**Treat unwanted features as malware**

*Isolate* the process. There's various things you can do, with various degrees of effectiveness depending on just how invasive the program's snooping is.

If all you want from it is the chatbox, there's no reason it should run on the same (virtual) computer that you're gaming on.

- Run it in a container or Virtual Machine. There's various methods: Qubes, KVM, FireJail, VMWare, and so on; or:
- Run it as a separate user with minimal/no permissions except what it absolutely needs (network access, I suppose), or:
- Use the browser version (which runs in the browser's sandbox, and thus has no access to your other programs).

Also: Give it it's own internet connection (proxy or VPN) if you think it can/will do an end-run around this. Bit paranoid, as it's unlikely it effectively can.

Or, I guess, if you don't want it isolated, you'll have to *reverse engineer* it and strip out the bits of code that do the thing you do not want (look for hooks/calls to OS functions that enumerate processes, trace from there, replace function calls with NOPs). How difficult that is depends on how much obfuscation effort was made and what language the program is written in.

Also, even though this would be much harder, it'd be much better in general if people [**stopped using closed-source software**](https://medium.com/@sammyjohnsonweb/use-riot-not-discord-for-foss-and-privacy-respecting-communities-d25f9ae2cb5) for utilities like this. There's many alternatives that *do* respect the user's wishes and *do not* phone home, spy, access memory/processes, and do [who knows what else](https://tosdr.org/en/service/536), protected by inane IP laws written by technophobes.

Comment: Regarding the second-to-last paragraph: there are reports that Discord is quite effective at deleting accounts of people who attempt to modify the software.

Answer (score 2):

#### run it in a virtual machine (VM)

- pick a VM software that can run on your OS (i like Virtualbox and it works on Linux/mac/windows. lets say you use virtualbox. there are other VM software you can use.)
- use Virtualbox to create a VM with 3 GB memory (i say 3GB because i use Cinnamon and it uses 2+ GB memory) and 1 core and storage with 100 GB dynamic (dynamic means it only uses disk space on the host as the VM writes new files)
- install Linux on the VM (i suggest Debian "stable")

  - [optional] install Virtualbox guest-additions to make mouse/keyboard easier to use
- install Discord on the VM
- start discord in the VM and start using it
- done

now that Discord is in a VM it can not see your active video games.

p.s. i know another user suggested use a VM. but his post does not give the specific steps needed on how to create and use a VM and so i think my post is significantly different than his.

Comment: In his answer on using a web client, Invizio mentioned not being able to use some functions of the regular client, like push-to-talk with voice comms. Is the VM'ed client still able to receive these while in game?

Comment: in theory a VM can use the host microphone and speakers. in practice, you would need to test it to see if it actually works.

Comment: Considering this is SE, I think the 'in practice' part is the most important :)